# How do I add numbers following a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, numbers

I want to console.log a string but also add numbers inside of it. For example if I use the following code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
  if (coinFlip === 1) {
    console.log("#" + i + 1 + " Heads");
  } else {
    console.log("#" + i + 1 + " Tails");
  }
}
```

Since what I want to console.log starts with a string I can't seem to add numbers right after it. They become strings.

I want to get:
"#2 Tails"

But I get:
"#11 Tails"

How do I get "#2 Tails" instead of "#11 Tails"?

Comment: `"#" + (i + 1) + " Heads"` or `\`#${i + 1} Heads\``

Comment: If you need your output to start with `1` why do you loop from `0` in the first place?

Comment: > "If you need your output to start with 1 why do you loop from 0 in the first place?"



Good question. I only had to do a for loop without the "# ..." added to it. After I did that I was playing around with the code and found out I didn't know how to add within a string. I was not able to figure out what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your addition in brackets.

```
console.log("#" + (i + 1) + " Heads");
```

or use string interpolation

```
console.log(`#${i+1} Heads`);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first sum up the value of `i` and `1` to `num` before the concatination

**1)**

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
  const num = i + 1;
  if (coinFlip === 1) {
    console.log("#" + num + " Heads");
  } else {
    console.log("#" + num + " Tails");
  }
}
```

**2)**

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
  if (coinFlip === 1) {
    console.log("#" + (i + 1) + " Heads");
  } else {
    console.log("#" + (i + 1) + " Tails");
  }
}
```

**3)**

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  coinFlip = Math.round(Math.random());
  if (coinFlip === 1) {
    console.log(`#${i + 1} Heads`);
  } else {
    console.log(`#${i + 1} Tails`);
  }
}
```